# Bootable service throwin sqlite database locked exception

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have an android service which is activated when device is booted , it is working properly when the app is active or is logged out of but if i force stop the app it is throwing exception, the service is trying to access database and throwing an sqllite database locked exception.Error log is shown below.DBHandler is the  class which is used to make database transactions and NotificationService is the service class.

getConfigData() method requires context which it is getting null when the app is closed.Is there way to solve this problem?

```
08-28 11:48:05.897: E/AndroidRuntime(5839): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-28 11:48:05.897: E/AndroidRuntime(5839): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.cwep.sync.NotificationService@414b4690 with null: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
08-28 11:48:05.897: E/AndroidRuntime(5839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2655)
08-28 11:48:05.897: E/AndroidRuntime(5839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:149)
08-28 11:48:05.897: E/AndroidRuntime(5839):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
08-28 11:48:05.897: E/AndroidRuntime(5839):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-28 11:48:05.897: E/AndroidRuntime(5839):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
08-28 11:48:05.897: E/AndroidRuntime(5839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
08-28 11:48:05.897: E/AndroidRuntime(5839):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-28 11:48:05.897: E/AndroidRuntime(5839):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-28 11:48:05.897: E/AndroidRuntime(5839):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
08-28 11:48:05.897: E/AndroidRuntime(5839):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
08-28 11:48:05.897: E/AndroidRuntime(5839):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-28 11:48:05.897: E/AndroidRuntime(5839): Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
08-28 11:48:05.897: E/AndroidRuntime(5839):     at android.app.ContextImpl.validateFilePath(ContextImpl.java:1705)
08-28 11:48:05.897: E/AndroidRuntime(5839):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:855)
08-28 11:48:05.897: E/AndroidRuntime(5839):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
08-28 11:48:05.897: E/AndroidRuntime(5839):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
08-28 11:48:05.897: E/AndroidRuntime(5839):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
08-28 11:48:05.897: E/AndroidRuntime(5839):     at com.cwep.dbhandler.DBHandler.getWritableDatabase(DBHandler.java:2756)
08-28 11:48:05.897: E/AndroidRuntime(5839):     at com.cwep.dbhandler.DBHandler.getConfigData(DBHandler.java:488)
08-28 11:48:05.897: E/AndroidRuntime(5839):     at com.cwep.sync.NotificationService.onStartCommand(NotificationService.java:58)
08-28 11:48:05.897: E/AndroidRuntime(5839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2638)
08-28 11:48:05.897: E/AndroidRuntime(5839):     ... 10 more
```

Comment: Can you show us the exception or an errorlog?

Comment: Do you have an open db connection you've forgot to close? An async task running which has a connection open for a long time maybe that needs a cancel method implemented. From the looks of your stack trace however, you are asking for the db connection but it's already used and open it looks like to me.

Comment: Will using bootable intent service instead of bootable service help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you passed an empty string `""` as a database name to `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor. You need to pass in a non-empty name that is valid as a filename, or a `null` (not an empty string) for an in-memory database.